# Minimum and maximum speeds in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet that contains the distance driven and the time. These are in columns B (distance) and C (time). Calculating the average speed is simple. Sum the distance and the time and divide the total distance driven by the total time used.

But how do I calculate the minimum speed and the maximum speeds?

To give an example: My last three rides have been 45,2 km/2:10 h, 13,6 km/0:45 h and 25,5 km/1:15 h. Out of these three, the first one has the greatest average speed of 20,9 kmh and the second the lowest at 18,1 kmh. How do I show this data in a cell? Do I need a script for that? If so, what should that look like?

Comment: =MIN(dataset) and =MAX(dataset)

Comment: Use the AVG Function.  See [Average Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/average-function-HP010062482.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an array formula. Where `B2:B10` are your distances and `C2:C10` are your times, paste the following into the formula bar and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=MAX(B2:B10/C2:C10)
```

The special array entry will make Excel interpret `B2:B10/C2:C10` as the array

```
{B2/C2, B3/C3, ..., B10/C10}
```

The `MAX` (or `MIN`) function then finds the maximum (or minimum) value in this array.

Comment: Thanks! This works quite good, but when I add new values, it doesn't update automatically but instead a small green mark appears on the top left corner to ask if I want to update the formula to contain the added rows. How do I automate this? Also, I had to format the formula to this: `{=MAX(B2:B19/((C2:C19)*24))}` Thats because there's something strange going on with the fields formatted as time.

Comment: After a little bit of research, I came up with this for the maximum speed: `{=MAX(INDIRECT("B2:B" & COUNTA(B2:B1000) + 1) / (INDIRECT("C2:C" & COUNTA(C2:C1000) + 1) * 24))}` Though there are still some hard coded values, but it's good for years. This seems to work for now, but do you see if there's anything that could cause problems?

Comment: @MikkoP That's probably the best way to go. You could also [format your data as a table](http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html). Excel will then extend the table as you add new rows. Your formula would then have to refer to the fields of the table instead of hard-coded column addresses. That should make sure your formulas include any added data.